# Rails association with a (non-activerecord) class (not a object/row)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

The problem:

People may have many types of degrees (bachelor, master, phd, etc...).
In my country, some degrees includes another.

Ex.: Superior Degree may be either bachelor or licentiate.

I'd like to create this structure in a class hierarchy:

```
Bachelor < Superior < Degree
Licentiate < Superior < Degree
Master < Degree
PHD < Degree
```

Those classes don't need to have rows stored in the Database, but I'd like to associate them with some ActiveRecord objects of other classes.

Should I just store classes name as strings?

Comment: Use polymorphic association.

Comment: [single table inheritence](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) is your friend

Comment: I havent tried yet, but polymorphic doesn't require {object}_id ? (which I wont have)

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord` associations work between instances of classes, not classes themselves. If you simply need a marker pointing to a certain type of degree, you could use an [`ActiveRecord::Enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) property on the `ActiveRecord`s having degrees. This would allow you to select records by their degrees.

That said, I would say your requirements easily justify a full ActiveRecord model. Use single table inheritance for the different degree types or even just one degree class, with a 'name' or 'type' property set to 'bachelor' and so on. Then one table row per degree type, having `has_many` (or `habtm` if it's n:m) associations to itself for the required degrees. The degrees would then be associated using regular rails associations (or polymorphic if you go with the STI variant).

If you don't want a table at all, you could also use [`ActiveModel::Associations`](https://github.com/joker1007/activemodel-associations), but then you would have to create the different degree instances from code, which is cumbersome.